# Node.js steam trade bot

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I'm trying to code with node.js for the first time, and have very small prior coding knowledge. I'm trying to code a steam trading bot, but I'm already stumped at the basics of it. This is the code I have, titled "bot.js":

```
const SteamUser = require('steam-user');
const client = new SteamUser();
const config = require('./config.json');

const logOnOptions = {
    accountName: config.username,
    password: config.password
};

client.logOn(logOnOptions);

client.on('loggedOn', () => {
console.log('Succesfully logged on.');
});
```

In the config.json file I just have the username and password which are fine. My problem is that when typing in node bot.js after installing steam-user, I get this error:

```
module.js:471
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Name\Desktop\bot\bot.js'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
at run (bootstrap_node.js:389:7)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
at bootstrap_node.js:504:3
```

Help?

Answer (score 0):

This is not an error with your code, but an error node is throwing saying it can't find `bot.js` in your directory `C:\Users\Name\Desktop\bot`

Verify that that is the directory where `bot.js` lives and that the file name is indeed `bot.js`. Also make sure there are no hidden extensions, the file could possibly be `bot.js.txt`.